# Geomesa's Z3 index must be unique?

Tags: geomesa

My key table are: timestampe, longitude, latitude, anotherAttr. Most of the queries impose conditions on latitude, longitude and timestamp. However they are not key, because they don't identify univoquely a record. So I'm wondering if I could set as key in Accumulo timestampe, longitude, latitude, anotherAttr and then use in my Z3 index of Geomesa timestampe, longitude, latitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoMesa implements the GeoTools API. Each feature has a unique primary key called the feature ID. This is used to prevent key collisions in the z3 index (and all other indices). The Z3 value itself is not unique.